# Chrome developer tools header formats and view source

Tags: http-headers, google-chrome-devtools

Below are two screenshots from the same version of Chrome. I would like to know when and why header names sometimes are displayed with different word capitalization and also when is the view source/view parsed toggle available? I've read the developer tools documentation which says nothing about it and tried to load pages in different ways. The only pattern i suspect is content compression, could that be it?

**Update:** nope seen both versions on sites using gzip

[image: headers 1]
[image: headers 2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that it happens only for resources served over HTTP2/SPDY (compare [this image served over HTTP2](https://www.google.pl/images/srpr/logo11w.png) with [the same image served over HTTP](http://www.google.pl/images/srpr/logo11w.png)). There is an old Chrome [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73945) that proves that HTTP2/SPDY headers are being handled differently. I reported this as a bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=502874).

Comment: Ok that seems to be one case for lower case and no view source. But i see it for some HTTP1 sites also :( e.g. two sites using HTTP1, TLS and gzipped response with different header formats: https://castaway.se and https://stackoverflow.com none of of them shows view source for me also.

Comment: @MattiasWadman castaway.se is served over HTTP2 (there is a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http2-and-spdy-indicator/mpbpobfflnpcgagjijhmgnchggcjblin?hl=en) that lets you easily check that). As for stackoverflow, headers are displayed [just fine](https://imgur.com/gTZ3Soo). Try again in incognito mode (so that we are sure that it's not an exensions fault).

Comment: Oh your right! castaway.se is my site... and now i see that the frontend setup i use [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/blob/master/nginx.tmpl) actually enables spdy... that is nice i guess. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The headers, for HTTP2, are in a binary format. I assume that is the reason why there is no option to show them.